Is there a "happens before" relationship if we merely add some acquire operation?
Say we have two global variables:
constinit int x = 0;
std::atomic_int i = 0;

Furthermore, we have two threads A and B that concurrently do the following:
// thread A
x = 1;
i.store(1, std::memory_order::release);

// thread B
i.load(std::memory_order::acquire);
x = 2;

Intuitively, this is a data race because x = 1 and x = 2 can happen at the same time.
There is no mutex, no if statement, no nothing that would prevent x = 1 and x = 2 from being done simultaneously.
You can't just dump a random ignored load somewhere and expect this to get rid of data races.
However, based on my reading of the standard, this is not a data race!
x = 1 happens before x = 2 because:

i.store(1, std::memory_order::release) synchronizes with i.load(std::memory_order::acquire); because any release operation synchronizes with any load operation on the same atomic object ([atomics.order] p2).
The load inter-thread happens before x = 2 because the load synchronizes with the store and the store is sequenced before x = 2 ([intro.races] p9.3.1).
x = 1 inter-thread happens before x = 2 because x = 1 is sequenced before the load and the load inter-thread happens before x = 2 ([intro.races] p9.3.2).

Because x = 1 happens before x = 2, there is no data race.
Furthermore, since x = 1 and x = 2 are the only modifications of x (after initialization) and because x = 1 is a visible side effect by definition, thread B would be guaranteed to obtain the value 1 for x if it was to read it instead of writing to it.
Obviously, I must be missing something. But what am I missing?
Maybe this is also a defect. [intro.races] p14 says that:

The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, is the value stored by some unspecified side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.

This "unspecified" makes it so that even if a store synchronizes with a load, that load can obtain a value from an unspecified prior side effect.
However, regardless of whether it is executed after, the load is said to happen after the store, which brings some thread safety where it seemingly should not.


because any release operation synchronizes with any load operation on the same atomic object ([atomics.order] p2).

This is wrong. The store only synchronizes with the load if ([atomics.order] p2)

[the load] takes its value from any side effect in the release sequence headed by [the store].

If it happens to do so (it is unspecified whether it does; see [intro.races] p14) then there is no data race.
Otherwise, the inter-thread happens before relationship falls apart, and there is a data race.

Whether or not you have a data race UB depends on whether i.load(std::memory_order::acquire); (informally) happens after i.store(1, std::memory_order::release);.
Or, technically speaking, if .load() happens to "take its value from any side effect in the release sequence headed by [the .store()]".

And formally, if one choice of unspecified behavior results in UB, then the whole execution has UB.

@user17732522 Huh, any source for that?

See https://eel.is/c++draft/intro#abstract-5.sentence-2. Note that "any such execution" refers to any of the permitted execution paths of the nondeterministic abstract machine for the given program and input. The nondeterministic aspect of execution is the result of unspecified behavior per https://eel.is/c++draft/intro#abstract-3.


x = 1 happens before x = 2 because ...

That is NOT guaranteed.  This IS a data race, because until the store() and load() statements are actually entered, the OS is free to switch between threads at will.  So, it could switch to thread B before thread A has executed x = 1, and then switch back to thread A after thread B has executed x = 2. Thus, x = 2 CAN happen before x = 1.
Only the store() and load() operations will sync with each other to avoid a data race on the value stored inside the atomic. Anything else that is done outside of those calls is still subject to races.
